# How is Dropbox web upload so fast?

Tags: compression, dropbox

I know that the Dropbox app does all sorts of compression before syncing files/folders (such as 7-zip and bzip, found by inspecting the list of FOSS that Dropbox uses in its Mac OSX client)

So, I wasn't too surprised that syncing a 95Mb video took only a minute on Dropbox. What was surprising, though, was that uploading the same video through their web interface was approximately just as fast!

Does anybody know how they accomplish this?

Comment: Most videos distributed online are already highly compressed to begin with, and do not benefit from additional compression.

Comment: So you are saying that the compression tools are not being used in the native Dropbox app, at least not for videos?

Comment: Also is there any way to track network activity to determine the length of content being sent to Dropbox servers?

I've heard of wireshark but have never used it, unsure if it can accomplish this task.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but if you were to compress a MP4 using the H.264 and AAC codecs, you wouldn't see much is any reduction in file size, it might even get bigger. WireShark could tell you how much data being sent to a server. You wouldn't be able to filter by program or tell what is in a request if it is over HTTPS, but you would still be able to see how much data is sent to an address.

Comment: 1.6 Mbit/s?  That's not so fast.